# Firefox for ubuntu renders wrong colors

Tags: css, macos, firefox, ubuntu, colors

I've got the following problem:

I'm developing an website, so while I was testing around I've noticed that firefox and chromium display an css bar in different colors. When I switched between several machine I could come to the conclusion that firefox for ubuntu is the problem. On all other devices I've tested the website. It's perfectly fine.

The differences between chrome and firefox rendering:

Firefox:

[image: firefox example:]

Chromium:

[image: chrome example:]

NOTE: Firefox for ubuntu is certainly the problem.

Does someone knows why this is and came up with a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=655637

Bug 629312 - Firefox displays wrong colors on image (only Linux)

open about:config 
and rechange the gfx.color_management.mode from 2 to 0.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem! After doing this and a reboot it worked perfectly.