# Color difference in firefox vs chrome?

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox, background-color

so I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox) before, but applying the fixes there didn't work for me (changing force-color-profile to sRGB in chrome).

I have my personal website [here](https://leshawnrice.com), and I guess I never checked it on firefox, which is now my default browser, but in firefox it renders the background photo's bg as #1b1b1b but in chrome it renders as #151515.

How can I fix this? I was thinking I could just crop the background out of the image and recenter it to avoid the bg conflict altogether, but I'm also curious what exactly is going on.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand. Which element's background renders as #1b1b1b? Both Chrome and FF give #151515 for the body background.

Comment: On my machine the two browsers render the same color #151515. Checked with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

As [A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth) and [Azu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12806767/azu) pointed out, this issue is not consistent. I believe this is a Linux-only issue, and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483428/firefox-for-ubuntu-renders-wrong-colors).

If you're having the same issue and are on linux, as the accepted answer says:

"open about:config and rechange the `gfx.color_management.mode` from `2` to `0`."